# MS SQL Server wrapping recursive derived classes of xml

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, recursion, sql-server-2016

I have a class hierarchy where entities can be subordinate to each other to designate employees, users or ownership of other entities. However each type of Entity is a derived c# class (e.g. a business or an individual) with completely different attributes. (For ease of readability I have removed namespaces, non-essential attributes and irrelevant subordinate elements).

For example:

```
<Root>
  <Entities>
     <Entity type="business" name="x">
        <Entities>
           <Entity type="individual" firstname "a" />
           <Entity type="business" name="y"/>
              <Entities>
                 <Entity type="individual" firstname="b"/>
              </Entities>
           </Entity>
        </Entities>
     </Entity>
     <Entity type="business name="z"/>
   </Entities>
</Root>
```

My solution was to create a stored procedure which retrieved the first entities, and then called scalar-valued functions which recursively called the remaining entities. This is the initial stored procedure:

```
select @EntityIndividualID as '@AuthorizedUserEntityID',
    (select null,
    (
        [dbo].[fn_GetBusinesses] (@EntityIndividualID, @Application)
    ),
    (
        [dbo].[fn_GetIndividuals] (@EntityIndividualID, @EntityIndividualID, @Application)
    )
    FOR xml path('Entities'), type)
FOR xml path('Root'), type
```

This works fine prior to recursion, however if I add code to each underlying function that wraps the underlying recursive calls for subordinate entities in an enclosing  element, it creates a never-ending recursion. This happens because even though there are no elements under the  element, SQL doesn't know that and places the wrapper anyway, example:

```
<Root>
   <Entities>
      <Entity type="business" name="a" />
         <Entities />
      </Entity>
   </Entities>
</Root>
```

My next thought was to use a UNION ALL of the various Entity types, however because each contains different attributes, that didn't work.

The questions is: What is the best practice for recursive queries based on derived classes such as this? Should I be aliasing each query and then join them somehow? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution took some work, but was accomplished by aliasing the nested queries in a scalar function.

Ignoring the recursion, which was handled by recursively calling a scalar function as before, the function returned xml data elements via one of (in my case) six alias queries, which then wrapped them in a root element.

An example of one of the 6 aliases:

```
select @xmlC = (select x.type as '@xsi:type', e.id as '@entityid'
FROM Entity_<type1> x inner join
Entity e on e.ID = x.EntityID 
FOR XML PATH('Entity'), TYPE, ELEMENTS);
```

then the wrapper:

```
select @xmlCombined = (select @xmlA, @xmlB, @xmlC, @xmlD, @xmlE, @xmlF 
for xml path(''), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT('Entities'));
```

then because it was performed in a function, returning the xml object:

```
RETURN @xmlCombined
```

Because some alias type further recursed from fn_GetSubordinateEntities, the same function was called from within one of the aliases, such as this:

```
FROM Entity_AuthorizedServices eas INNER JOIN ServiceOrder_Type sot ON sot.ID = eas.ServiceOrder_TypeID
where eas.EntityID = E.ID
FOR XML PATH('Entity_AuthorizedService'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT('Entity_AuthorizedServices')),   
(
   [dbo].[fn_GetSubordinateEntities] (@EntityIndividualID, E.ID, @Application)
)
```